# In c# why (char)(1) + (char)(2) results in int 3

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, char

I am trying to covert some VB.NET code to C# and found this interesting thing.
Adding two chars returns different results in VB.NET and C#.

**VB.NET** - *returns string*

```
Chr(1) & Chr(2) = "  "
```

**C#** - *returns int*

```
(char)(1) + char(2) = 3
```

How can i add(concatenate) two chars in C#?

Comment: You mean concatenate?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong - c# and java char and int arr of same size & 0001 + 0010 = 0011(3) .

Comment: @Blam - yes Concatenate

Comment: `"" + (char)1 + (char)2`? Not nice but should work. Also: `string.Concat((char)1, (char)2)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C# [`char` is a 16-bit numeric type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx), so `+` means addition, not concatenation. Therefore, when you add `a` and `b` you get `a+b`. Moreover, the result of this addition is an `int` ([see a quick demo](http://ideone.com/RDIjk1)).

If by "adding two characters" you mean "concatenation", converting them to a strings before applying operator `+` would be one option. Another option would be using `string.Format`, like this:

```
string res = string.Format("{0}{1}", charA, charB);
```

Comment: +1 Sadly you have skipped the most interesting part... Why in C# many operations upcast to int :-)

Comment: Well, you still need to answer the question :P

Comment: Ahaa... Now i got it. 
Tried all the answers mentioned here and `string.Format` seems to be the neatest way of doing it. 
Also the answer from xanatos and Corak are good, but it may confuse the team in future.

Comment: The answer can be shortened to `string res = string.Concat(charA, charB);`

Comment: @JeowLiHuan You are right and string.Concat() always give better performance than stringBuilder and string.Format().

Answer (score 5):

By adding to an empty string you can force the "conversion" of `char` to `string`... So

```
string res = "" + (char)65 + (char)66; // AB
```

(technically it isn't a conversion. The compiler knows that when you add to a `string` it has to do some magic... If you try adding `null` to a string, it consider the `null` to be an empty string, if you try adding a `string` it does a `string.Concat` and if you try adding anything else it does a `.ToString()` on the non-string member and then `string.Concat`)

Answer (score 3):

The best answer is in the comments so I want elevate it here to a proper answer. With full credit going to @Jeow Li Huan:

```
string res = string.Concat(charA, charB);
```

Answer (score 0):

(char)(1) has an ascii value of 1 and 
(char)(2) ascii value of 2

so ascii value of 1 + 2 (i.e. (char)1 + (char)2 ) will be equal to 3.

if you do:
"2" + "1" this will give you "21" (althou you should not use this to join strings, bad practice)

if you do:
'2' + '1' this will give you int value of 99 that is ascii value of 2 (which is 50) + ascii value of 1(which is 49).

Comment: Why is it a bad practice?