# error setting variable to specific character in char array / string to char[] array to string[] array to string

Tags: c#

What you see here is a little bit of the code from a project that I am currently working on. I am making a BruteForce program because I was Challenged by my friend to test his login system on his website.

I need to check each password against his program, and to do so I have created this while loop which loops through my array of chars, checking all possible passwords with the length of 1 then 2 then 3 .....

The variable `Attempt` will repeatedly be set to a new string made of whatever chars is in my char[] array on the positions described by the manny `ArrayX[___]`.....

This is done in this line of code `Attempt = ArrayX[Eight] + ArrayX[Seventh] + ArrayX[Sixth] + ArrayX[Fifth] + ArrayX[Fourth] + ArrayX[Third] + ArrayX[Second] + ArrayX[First];`

The problem is that i get an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type int to string" as if the code thinks that the int represented by the variable `ArrayX[_"""Here"""_]` is something that it is supposed to convert to a string to fit it into the variable `Attempt`.

Now I know this code is far from perfect because I am very much still learning (i am in my first half year of the education). BUT I know for a fact that this code works perfectly IF I were using a string[] array instead of a char[] array.
But I don't know how to convert a char[] array into a string[] array, and I absolutely cannot type each and every character manually into a sting array as I am working with an array of 10000+ characters.

If anyone has an idea as to how I can solve my problem I would be most grateful. (please keep in mind that this piece of code has to run as fast as possible, so I want to (if possible) not make it to complex so it won't slow down much)

This is some of my code(This is C#):

```
char[] ArrayX = ssss.ToCharArray();

while (PasswordNotFound)
      {
            if (First == ArrayX.Length)
            {
                Second++;
                First = 0;
            }
            if (Second == ArrayX.Length)
            {
                Third++;
                Second = 0;
            }
            if (Third == ArrayX.Length)
            {
                Fourth++;
                Third = 0;
            }
            if (Fourth == ArrayX.Length)
            {
                Fifth++;
                Fourth = 0;
            }
            if (Fifth == ArrayX.Length)
            {
                Sixth++;
                Fifth = 0;
            }
            if (Sixth == ArrayX.Length)
            {
                Seventh++;
                Sixth = 0;
            }
            if (Seventh == ArrayX.Length)
            {
                Eight++;
                Seventh = 0;
            }
            if (Eight == ArrayX.Length)
            {
                break;
            }

            Attempt = ArrayX[Eight] + ArrayX[Seventh] + ArrayX[Sixth] + ArrayX[Fifth] + ArrayX[Fourth] + ArrayX[Third] + ArrayX[Second] + ArrayX[First];

            First++;
            Cracks++;
      }
```

Comment: Show sample for `ssss` and also mention type of `Attempt `

Comment: `Attempt` is predefined as an empty string.

Comment: `ssss` = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ0123456789! ""#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`_{|}~ÇüéâäàåçêëèïîìÄÅÉæÆôöòûùÿÖÜø£Ø×ƒáíóúñÑªº¿®¬½¼¡«»░▒▓│┤ÁÂÀ©╣║╗╝¢¥┐└┴┬├─┼ãÃ╚╔╩╦╠═╬¤ðÐÊËÈıÍÎÏ┘┌█▄¦Ì▀ÓßÔÒõÕµþÞÚÛÙýÝ¯´≡±‗¾¶§÷¸°¨·¹³²■ "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around my problem.

This sems to do the trick:

```
Attempt = string.Concat(ArrayX[Eight].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty), ArrayX[Seventh].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty), ArrayX[Sixth].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty), ArrayX[Fifth].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty), ArrayX[Fourth].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty), ArrayX[Third].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty), ArrayX[Second].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty), ArrayX[First].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty));
```

The `string.Concat()` works better then using `+`

And the `.ToString()` turns the char into a string.

And the `.Replace(" ", string.Empty)` removes the spaces that i dont want to be displayed before they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
string arraychar=new string(ArrayX);
```

Comment: Could you pls tell me what you want me to do with this piece of code?

Comment: You wanted a way to convert an array of char to string, this is the way, given ArrayX is char[]

Answer (score 0):

When you add 2 chars using `+`, you will get an int as the result, since char is a numeric type. If you want to treat them as strings and concatenate them, you need to use some other method. See [In c# why (char)(1) + (char)(2) results in int 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335482/in-c-sharp-why-char1-char2-results-in-int-3) for various possibilities.